# MS Excel is automatically protecting worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a MS Excel sheet that is, periodically, being automatically protected.  How do I stop this from happening?

I can manually unprotect it, but since I am frequently modifying and saving this document, I would like to just have it remain unprotected.

Does anyone know what might be causing this behavior?

Thanks!

Comment: Does anyone else access/edit that same copy of the document?  Perhaps someone else it protecting it...?  Are there any mocros in the Excel document (that may be protecting it one save, or alike)?  If you make a copy of the Excel document and use that one, does it behave the same way?

Comment: I am the only one who has this copy of the document.  And yes even if I make a copy of the document the problem persists.  As far as macros go, I looked at the macros in the developer ribbon, but I didn't see any that seemed like they would cause this.

Comment: If you make a copy and it keeps happening, then it's something (legitimately) in the document.  You'll have to examine your macros better to confirm they're not doing it. Look for "Worksheet.Protect" or alike.

Comment: Ok, Once I dove into the macros deeper I did find that.  Thanks!

Comment: Nice, glad you found it. I'll throw up an 'official' answer. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you copy the Excel document and the locking still persists, then there's something inside the document that's legitimately there and protecting the sheet, most likely in a VBA macro.

Examine all macros for use of the [Worksheet.Protect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840611.aspx) method.